# Export html to Docx in JavaScript - getting corrupted word file

Tags: html, docx

I need to update some JavaScript that exports HTML to Word so that the file is .docx instead of .doc. I am unable to use any API's or Libraries to accomplish this task. I am using vanilla JavaScript and JQuery.
The current code is below. The source where I got this code snippet states "By default, the word file will be saved as a .doc file. If you want to export word file as a .docx file, specify the extension in the file name." ( https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-to-word-doc-docx-using-javascript/ )
When I change the filename to ".docx", the Word document that is downloaded is corrupted. I appreciate any help you are able to provide.

```
function Export2Word(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

I tried this function with ".docx" file extension and the Word file is still coming in corrupted:

```
<script>
    function exportHTML(){
       var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' "+
            "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' "+
            "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>"+
            "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title></head><body>";
       var footer = "</body></html>";
       var sourceHTML = header+document.getElementById("source-html").innerHTML+footer;
       
       var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
       var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
       document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
       fileDownload.href = source;
       fileDownload.download = 'document.docx';
       fileDownload.click();
       document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
    }
</script>
```

I tried changing the headers to:

````
var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' "+
            "xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' "+
            "xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types' "+
            "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title></head><body>";```

I tried changing data to:
````

```
   var source = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
```

```
none of the other Stack Overflow solutions have worked. Thanks again for any help you can provide
```